# Regex to match any integer greater than 1

Tags: regex

I recently just picked up on regex and I am trying to figure out how to match the pattern of any numbers greater than 1.
so far I came up with

```
[2-9][0-9]*
```

But it only works with the leftmost digit not being 1. For example, `234` works but `124` doesn't.

So what am I trying to achieve is that a single digit of `1` shouldn't be matched and any integer greater than it should.

Comment: Use regex101.com for your tries, the solution isn't so difficult.

Comment: **regex isn't a programming language**, there's no such thing as `x > 1` in regex. Capture the numbers with a regex and use a programming language to process the match.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte ***"the solution isn't so difficult."*** I'd say, impossible with a regex.

Comment: @PedroLobito: `1\d+|[2-9]\d*`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Doesn't  match `1.01` . I'm sure you know what's wrong with this question. **"regex to match any number greater than 1?"** . *greater* and regex don't mix...

Comment: @PedroLobito: I think decimal numbers are out of the scope of the question, but it can also be done (with the same idea: optional for `[2-9]`, mandatory for 1)

Comment: how about integers. I just updated it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte , I found weird someone with your rep answering a question like this without pointing the obvious, but that's fine, life goes on. GL

Comment: @PedroLobito It's definitely possible with a regex, since the language of integers greater than 1 is regular. It's also a reasonable thing to do if you're studying regexes or computability theory, though it has no place in production code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be using alteration to define two categories of numbers.

1. Less than 10.
2. Greater than or equal to 10.

**Regex:** `^(?:[2-9]|\d\d\d*)$`

**Explanation:**

`[2-9]` is for numbers less than 10.

`\d\d\d*` is for numbers greater than or equal to 10.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YHsmu1/5/)**

**Alternate solution considering preceding `0`**

**Regex:** `^0*(?:[2-9]|[1-9]\d\d*)$`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1doIYQ/3/)**

Comment: hm, that seems pretty advanced. why are there two categories and why the number 100???

Comment: It doesn't match 10 and matches 001.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Oh blimey ! need to format it a little bit. I guess `[2-9]\d*|\d\d\d\d*|10` will solve the problem.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I don't get how 1 wouldn't work in this case, wouldn't `\d*` matches with any digit?

Comment: @PegasusFantasy: I have updated my answer. Two categories because numbers less than 10 have only one digit, we can simply match it with `[2-9]`.  Numbers larger than 9 will have more than 2 digits in which case there should atleast be 2 digits, 3rd and beyond that are optional.

Comment: How about replacing the second part to `[1-9]\d+` for disallowing numbers that start with zero. But it's not clear from question if such as `001` is allowed or not. However, your current regex would allow `00` which is probably not wanted.

Comment: this matches `000000`, ***Stop trying to do math operations with a regex***, it's really sad to see this. ***You cannot assert if a number is greater, equal or smaller than other with a regex***

Comment: @bobblebubble: Since OP didn't mentioned about combination of digits like `00` or `0000`.

Comment: @PedroLobito: I know right. But incase it's not a calculation and just pattern matching ? Not clear in question.

Comment: Depending on the regex flavour (not specified in the question), `\d` may match more than you expect. And it should be noted that it doesn't accept other representations of integers that are usually accepted, such as `+1000` or `1,000`. The OP should have specified the regex flavour and precisely what should and shouldn't be accepted, and personally, I think at least until that time, the question should not have received an answer yet, it's unavoidably too much based on guesswork.

Comment: Would think most applications of this regex would want to disallow numbers with trailing zeros (e.g. `002`). Would suggest revamping this answer to give`^(?:[2-9]|[1-9]\d+)$` as the primary solution.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick.
    [0]*([2-9]+|[1-9][0-9][0-9]*)

Comment: What about `002` ?

Comment: thanks for pointing out, fixed it.focussed on 001 not to be valid.

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
^[2-9]|[1-9]\d+$
```

See example [here](https://regex101.com/r/owfkJP/2)