# Regex to match numbers greater than or equal one

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex to match number greater than or equal one. I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574113/regex-to-match-any-integer-greater-than-1)

```
Regex: ^(?:[2-9]|\d\d\d*)$
```

But, I do not get why there is `?:` before the number? Also, if the number in my case is in the middle of sentence, then I should remove the following `^( )$` from my regex?

**EDIT:**

I need grate than or equal 1 not just greater than. So I should use [1-9] instead of [2-9]?

**EDIT2:** 
I need a regex to capture any number greater than or equal to the number `1`.
Example: `2,3,4, 11, 100, 31557600` or any number greater than that.

Comment: `?:` indicates a non-capturing group. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do

Comment: You can use word boundaries if you want to match numbers in a larger text and use `\b(?:[2-9]|[1-9]\d+)\b` and you can't use `[1-9]` instead of `[2-9]` else it will match `1` also.

Comment: @BlackPearl I read your link. I do not get why it is used in the number case? What do I want to ignore? In the link example, they want to ignore part, and just use it in the matching process.

Comment: If you do want to get the matched text within the `()` and just need to validate it, you use `?:`. If you need the actual match, you should not use it.

Comment: @Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi If I want to capture 1 also? just change [2-9] to p[1-9]?

Comment: @user9371654: If you want to capture one or greater than one then better use just `\b[1-9]\d*\b`

Comment: Yes, you should use [1-9] if you want to capture numbers greater than 1, and as @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi suggested, you should use `\b` if the number is in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: Also, what if the number is greater than 3 digits?

Comment: `\b[1-9]\d*\b` this will match any number greater than or equal to `1` and hence will match a number greater than three digits like 1234 too. Can you precisely state, what do you really want to achieve?

Comment: @Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi  see edit2

Comment: @user9371654: Yes my regex above will match all your numbers. [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ht3Bcj/1)

Comment: Why? This is like asking how can I slice a cake with a chainsaw? Regex is clearly the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: What else do you suggest? This is part of a longer regex which contains other strings and the number is just part of it.

Comment: @Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi do you mean d* or d+? you have mentioned both in separate comments. Wich one is correct? I think d*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ?: is to just look for the pattern without capturing. Your case seems to be different. Also, the () are to create a group, again, you do not need that functionality as your use case is quite simple.

If the numbers won't be like 000 (ie no extra initial zeroes), then you can go with
`^[1-9]\d*$`. If the numbers can come in between the sentences, use `\b[1-9]\d*\b` to look for word boundaries.

The basic idea is this: you want to match any non-negative number that is not zero.
So, the number should not start with a `-` or `0`. So, start with 1-9 (`\b[1-9]` part of regex), followed by any digits (`\d*\b` part of regex).

Obviously this leaves out many forms of numbers: floats as decimals (eg 23.456), numbers in exponential form (eg 1.23e4) etc.