# Gitlab Rules operator - can we use number operator like >= to 1?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

i have only seen == and =~ but can gitlab use >= 1 ?
is there any example?

```
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main" && $NUMBER >= 1'
  when: always
```

This did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only [use the equality and regex match operators](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#cicd-variable-expressions).

However, you can [make a regex with equivalent behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574154/5747944).